# an unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, com-interop

I get the following exception when trying to load an ASP.NET MVC website:

> Unhandled exception at 0x07070a91 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000000.

The Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger opens and the only information I can see in the debugger is this:

> **Call stack location:**
>
> msvbvm60.dll!06c00a91()

The website uses some COM objects and everything worked fine until last week. This problem appeared out of the blue.

This is the error log from Windows Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
>   Faulting module name: MSVBVM60.DLL, version: 6.0.98.15, time stamp: 0x4a5bda6c
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00030a91
>   Faulting process id: 0x1a0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cd31fcb47f66d8
>   Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVBVM60.DLL
>   Report Id: f5db0ae3-9def-11e1-ad79-005056c00008

Do you have any suggestions to help troubleshoot this problem?

**Edit:** I managed to solve the problem and now everything works. The solution involved tweaking some registry settings that the custom dlls need in order to function properly. So the problem didn't actually appear out of the blue, I just didn't realize some registry values were modified, which caused a com dll to crash.

Comment: Are these custom COM objects you're calling into?

Comment: MSVBVM60 is the VB6 runtime dll. My guess is a changed full trust to partial trust, situation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The information you provided above is not enough to provide a root cause however if you can provide more info about the exception you might get exact reason for this failure. You asked for suggestion to troubleshoot this problem so here they are:

You can use either any one of the 3 tools to troubleshoot this issue:

1. IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2

   Here is more info about how to use this tool:
    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790
2. DebugDiag

   Use the link below to understand how you can hook your w3wp process (it is user mode proces) with DebugDiag and collect more info about the crash:

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx
3. WinDBG

   Here is a link which will help you to load W3WP process in WinDBG and use some commands to extract more info about the crash:

   http://blog.whitesites.com/Debugging-Faulting-Application-w3wp-exe-Crashes__634424707278896484_blog.htm

Once you have more info about the exception, you can add above and will get prompt help.

Answer (score 18):

Open the Advanced settings dialog of the Application pool that is serving the application in IIS Manager, and set: **Enable 32-Bit Applications** to ***True***

Comment: After over an hour of fruitlessly Googling around in the Microsoft forums and messing with IIS Debug Diagnostic Tool, this is what fixed it for me. Such a weird issue.

Comment: That also fix the issue on my side. Beside, I found that turning that setting to True and then immediatly set it to false again also fix the issue, but for a certain time... I have to do it once a day... This is kind of annoying. @IsaacLyman How long have you been experiencing this issue? For me it started on last friday, never had this before. I'm suspecting a faulty windows update...

Comment: @Marc-AndreR. A faulty Windows update is a definite possibility. I started experiencing it only a couple of days ago. I clicked "Set Application Pool Defaults", changed the setting to True (which changed it for all or my app pools permanently) and I haven't had any trouble with it since.

Comment: hy, this resolve my issue.Thank you so much. Can you explain how this trick works and what the reason for throwing this error.

Comment: Hi @Ajith when you publish your app in release mode, it by default build for x86 architecture and by default IIS in 64bit windows start the worker process in 64bit. I haven't tested with an AnyCPU build through.

Answer (score 3):

Do the Following,

1) Give full rights to Temp & %temp% folders

2) Go to application pool properties & Change " Enable 32 bit application " to true

Comment: I think the %temp% folder full access did it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may start by capturing a crash dump when this issue happens again,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960

Use Debug Diag 1.2 to set up a crash rule properly is step 1.

Once you have the dump, you can use WinDbg (part of Debugging Tools for Windows) to analyze it if you are familiar with dump analysis.

If you are not capable of analyzing that, my suggestion is that you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dumps with Microsoft support engineers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a program called "Web Companion" was installed.

After uninstalling it, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution is if you want to build it on 64bit:**

Debug ==> Options ==> Search for iis ==> enable using of 64bit Version of IIS Express

Answer (score 0):

This was the fix that worked for me while publishing WebAPI 7.0 to IIS on Windows 10 Enterprise Edition:

1. Open IIS.
2. Go to your Application Pool.
3. Right-click on it -> Advanced Settings...
4. Under Process Model, change Identify from "ApplicationPoolIndentity" to "LocalSystem".
5. Restart your IIS.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, It was occurring because there was an **infinite loop** over the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).