# Website frequently timing out, but can't determine why

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I'm after some general advice here. We have an ASP.net 4 web forms application on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5, with SQL Server 2008.  We're experiencing problems with the website timing out, seemingly at random.  We've had reports of what people were doing on the site when they noticed it started timing out, and there is no consistency between these.  We have also tried all of the things that users reported they were doing, and have had no joy bringing the site down.  We have static html pages on the site (albeit with .net4 friendly URLs) and these pages display when the site is timing out.

At first we thought it was a cyber attack, so spend time making sure all ports were closed, remote access only available to select IPs, and routing mail through an external spam filter (allowing us to close port 25). We also ran virus and malware scans which found nothing.

We have made updates to the website at the time that these problems started appearing, however it's really too late and too much has happened on the site that we could roll back the changes without experiencing a bigger headache than we currently are.

I'm a developer rather than a support/hosting/hardware specialist, so don't know huge amounts about server setups, but I've spent a long time going through error logs looking for some positive sign.  When I've looked at the error logs around the time the site went down, there has rarely been a error - sometimes there is a warning, but nothing that looks conclusive (this could be where my server inexperience could be a problem however). I'm not ruling out there being multiple issues by the way.

I set up IIS debugging tool as I noticed a w3wp.exe error yesterday (similar to this: [an unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589029/an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-w3wp-exe)), but the site has continued to go down today with nothing new in the debugger. I've debugged the site locally through VS2010 and can't recreate any issue.

So really, I'm on the point where I've run out of ideas, and almost run out of hair to pull out. Can anyone who's a bit more clued up in this area, offer me some advice or a list of things to try in order to pinpoint exactly what is happening here and what is causing it to hang?  Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Do you have any long running processes in any of the pages? Are you doing any threading in the application code? Essentially, what I'm getting at is if you're in any way starving the thread pool.

Comment: No no long processes at all. Quick trips to the database is really all. Don't think the site uses threading at all either

Comment: the site is using threading as ASP.NET uses it internally. But any slow running page **or** improperly closed DB connections, among other things, can lead to this. What are the specific details are you getting in the error? Is this an SQL Timeout, HTTP Timeout, etc.

Comment: That's the main issue - there is rarely details of an error.  The site just hangs until we restart it in IIS, and when I check error logs, elmah, or IIS logging, there is no sign of what happened to bring it down!  For database connections, we use table adapters and stored procedures - can they be improperly closed?

Comment: they can be improperly closed. If your db logic (in C#) doesn't properly close the connection it won't be returned to the connection pool. This leads to a timeout scenario as your pages start waiting for connections to be returned to the pool. Since you're getting no errors I have to ask how your site is deployed. Is it in debug or release mode? As by default ASP.NET will quit attempting to render a page after 110 seconds.

Comment: Hmm, I would have said release mode, but the web config says compilation debug="true". What would be the potential risks of deploying it in debug mode?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26038/discussion-between-frazell-thomas-and-e-on)

Comment: Still no firm solution to this issue, so any comments or suggestions appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Are there any 3rd party DLLs used on the site, perhaps some managed or wrapped unmanaged code isn't being released properly by IIS/worker processes and causing some kind of lock/deadlock/race condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that there were some `TableAdapters` in the site that were static and shared for the class.  After removing them, the problem stopped.  Thanks for the help anyway folks