# How to remove http response header in mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I want to remove http response header in mvc.

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html;
>   charst=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date:
>   Mon, 23 Feb 2015 12:43:58 GMT Content-Length: 4898 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive

I remove Connection, X-Powered-By, Server, Cache-Control with this code:

```
> protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender,EventArgs e)
> {
> HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
> HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
> HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
> HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
> HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
> }
```

but how can i do remove all http response header?

Comment: i can not remove Date, HTTP, Content-Type, Content-Length. please help me.

Comment: See comment on this (not so good) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30160598/1178314), your remove code may lead to server freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with more information on the reasons driving you to remove those headers, since this looks to me as a quite unusual need, especially for `content-type`. It may turn out you need to do something else.

Otherwise, read on.

Try with IISRewrite module. It should allow you to get them blank.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615970/1178314) or this [more detailed one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29386267/1178314).

If removing them is really what you require, you may have to write your own custom isapi filter. There is some information about this solution on this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012627/1178314).

For many of them, you may also consider disabling what adds them rather than removing them after they have been added. See [my answer on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17600445/1178314) for a bunch of them.