# Remove IIS server details in Angular application

Tags: angular, security

I am trying to hide server details when angular application after loading. help me to hide this details. I attached the screen shot for reference

[image]

Comment: Angular can't do that. 

It's your server that is "at fault" here, sending information about itself. 

Although not that dangerous, if you wish to remove it, please edit your tags to target the IIS community.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the server response header from IIS. Following is a question answer that might help you.

[Remove Server Response Header IIS 8.0 / 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401219/remove-server-response-header-iis-8-0-8-5)

First, you need to install the plugin and write the code like below in web.config file.

[image]

Basically you need to add rewrite module and overwrite that value with your value.

Comment: Thanks for ur response and can u share some sample code

Comment: It's a plugin. You need to download that and install it. Then in article itself they have mentioned the sample code.

Comment: I have updated answer by putting image